# Why Kafka Streams ignores repeated messages with the same value payload

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a stateful Kafka Streams application that reads *avro* data from two topics into `KTable`s, performs custom aggregation `groupBy` and `aggregate` for one of them, and joins to the second one.

When I send messages with the same key, but different values (different payload) everything works as expected and all messages are processed.

However, I've noticed that when I send multiple messages with the same key and the same value (same payload), the 2nd+ message is "ignored" and not processed. I.e. no new messages written into the output topic, no log messages from transformations appear.

This contradicts to my understanding of Kafka Stream processing. What is the reason of such behavior?

P.S.
I know that in `KTable` each new data record considered as an update and shows current value. However, I expect that each such update (even the repeated one) will still trigger the further processing, including aggregation and join.

Comment: Are you using Avro keys? The equality check for Avro is not really precise, I've found, so using it for keys isn't the best idea